# Coding drivers to support different modes on chipsets

Tags: driver, windows-kernel, ndis

If I wrote a brand new driver for non-supporting monitor mode or master mode chipsets, would it be possible to allow them to support these modes after?

For example, I have ALFA USB WiFi AWUS036NH which does not support Master Mode(AKA access point mode). It uses chipset Realtek RTL8812AU WLAN chipset.

If I wrote a brand new driver for this specific chipset, is it possible I could make it support Access point mode? (Not to mention I need to learn how to code drivers for this purpose)

Or like the WiFi card that my laptop is using (possibly not supporting anything other than managed-mode) if I wrote a driver for its chipset, is it possible I could have it support Monitor or Access Point Mode?